# Run Java as root through IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, root

I am trying to make IDEA run my Java program as root. I am running on Linux. Currently, I have the Terminal view open and just run the previous command, a gradle build command and the `sudo java -jar ...` command.

Would it be possible to make IDEA run Java as root in the configuration?

I thought about making a script to run Java as root, and pointing it to that as a new JVM, but IDEA doesn't recognize this as a Java installation.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo java $@
```

Could I somehow trick IDEA into thinking this is a JVM or is there a better way of running as root?

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? Running as root is usually the wrong thing.

Comment: I need to access serial ports and those are not allowed to be accessed on Linux under a normal user.

Comment: Sure they are; I do it all the time. You need to properly manage your permissions, which usually just means adding the user your program is running as to a group such as `uucp` or `serial`.

Comment: The `serial` group did not exist, but I added it to `uucp`. I still cannot access the port. I am using a USB to serial adapter if that changes anything, running Kubuntu 15.04

Comment: Doesn't change anything; they all show up as `/dev/ttyS?`. Check the actual ownership of that device node, and remember that you have to log out and back in or use `newgrp` to make new group memberships effective.

Comment: The device is `/dev/ttyUSB0`. The ownership is of `dialout`. I added myself to that group. I tried simply running `newgrp`, but it didn't work, I had to log out (I actually rebooted) and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way is to run idea as root. this is what I am doing when I need to access devices such as `/dev/input/eventX`. I don't want to change the permissions on those things.